# what is the meaning of each term in the two-dimensional wave equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, differential

$u_{t t}=\alpha^{2} u_{x x}+\beta^{2} u_{z z}+\left(\alpha^{2}-\beta^{2}\right) w_{x z}$

$w_{t t}=\beta^{2} w_{x x}+\alpha^{2} w_{z z}+\left(\alpha^{2}-\beta^{2}\right) u_{x z}$

were $u$ and $w$ are the horizontal and vertical displacements of each point in the medium, $\alpha$ is  the velocity of the logitudinal wave, $\beta$ is the velocity of the transverse wave.

what are the physical meaning of each term?

Comment: I don’t understand the question. The “physical meaning” is what you wrote. What else do you want to know?

Comment: I guess that every term of the sum has  a different meaning. Am I wrong?

Comment: Do you know the  “physical meaning” of the terms in the simpler equation $w_{t t}=w_{x x}$?